# file.lastModified() function does not give the updated value

Tags: java

`file.lastModified()`  not updated , although I change the file content , I work on Windows.
I use File of java , what could be the problem ? Do I need to do some kind of refresh from the code ?

Comment: Did you also close your stream after writing to that file? That is when on Windows this timestamp is changing

Comment: It is expensive to reset the time on every write, most likely it is only set when you close the file.

Comment: Does your filesystem support this information?

Comment: Hey i close the file, i didnt do the change in the code . i thought i will see the change on my code

Answer (score 4):

Java, at least 1.8 appears to be caching file attributes. I created a C++ application that uses the Win32's FindFirstFile to get the file information and verify that the last modified value is updated every time. And it does. But Java's File and Files both seem to not always get the latest value. Even tried a one second delay between writes and it didn't always get updated. I'm using Files.write to modify the file so I would hope it's closing it. Not sure if there's a good solution for this in Java, which is unfortunate.

UPDATE:

I found that Files.getLastModifiedTime is a solution for this. But it's only available for Java 1.8 or later.

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour is platform-dependent. Windows doesn't update the metadata of a file being modified until it is closed.

Answer (score 1):

If the file was loaded from the classpath resources, `files.lastModified()` might not detect the change after an edit is made.
However, when the file was loaded from the **outside of the application**, it did work well in my case (Windows 10, Java 10).

I've tested it by running `files.lastModified()` on a scheduled thread, the file reference was loaded once at the JVM startup.

So depending on how your file is loaded, it might affect how file modification is read.

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting `lastModified` time. it should work fine

```
 File file =new File("fileName");
 // other operations
 file.setLastModified(new Date().getTime()); // set time
```

Now you can get `lastUpdated` time back.

```
file.lastModified();
```

Comment: He isn't. He is 'changing the file content'. -1

Comment: i am doing the same which is not showing the updated time.